# Comparing Naive Inverse Filter to Wiener Filter for Deconvolution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, convolution, ifft

I am currently trying to compare a simple inverse filter to the wiener filter for deconvolution using matlab.  My starting signal is `exp(-t^2)` and this is to be convolved with a rect that is nonzero for times -.5 to .5.  I am introducing noise with amplitude in the range -.5 to .5.

Defining my time domain to frequency domain mapping:

```
f = exp(-t^2) => F

s = rect => R

c = f*s => C

r = noise (see above) => R

with noise c becomes: c = f*s + n => C = FxS + N
```

For the first approach I am simply taking the FT of `c` and dividing it by the FT of `f` and then doing an inverse FT. This is amounts to `s = (approx.) ifft((FxS + N)/F)`.

For the second approach I am taking the wiener filter, `W`,  and multiplying it against `C/R` and then doing an inverse FT.  This amounts to `S = (approx.) ifft(CxW/R)`.

The wiener filter is `W = mag_squared(FxS)/(mag_squared(FxS) + mag_squared(N))`.

I have used '*' to mean convolution and 'x' to mean multiplication.

I am trying to compare the two deconvolutions of the rect over the time interval -3 to 3.
Right now, my resulting graphs of the deconvolved rect look nothing like the original.
Could someone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing to wrong?  I have tried using ifftshift and different scalings in many different orderings but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

My matlab code is below:

```
%%using simple inverse filter
dt = 1/1000;
t = linspace(-3,3,1/dt); %time
s = zeros(1,length(t)); 
s(t>=-0.5 & t<=0.5) = 1; %rect
f = exp(-(t.^2)); %function
r = -.5 + rand(1,length(t)); %noise

S = fft(s);
F = fft(f);
R = fft(r);
C = F.*S + R;
S_temp = C./F;
s_recovered_1 = real(ifft(S_temp));  %correct?...works for signal without R (noise)

figure();
plot(t,s + r);
title('rect plus noise');

figure();
hold on;
plot(t,s,'r');
plot(t,f,'b');
legend('rect input','function');
title('inpute rect and exponential functions');
hold off;

figure();
plot(t,s_recovered_1,'black');
legend('recovered rect');
title('recovered rect using naive filter');


%% using wiener filter
N = length(s);
I_mag = abs(I).^2;
R_mag = abs(R).^2;
W = I_mag./(I_mag + R_mag);
S_temp = (C.*W)./F;
s_recovered_2 = abs(ifft(S_temp));  

figure();
freq = -fs/2:fs/N:fs/2 - fs/N;
hold on;
plot(freq,10*log10(I_mag),'r');
plot(freq,10*log10(R_mag),'b');
grid on
legend('I_mag','R_mag');
title('Periodogram Using FFT')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)')

figure();
plot(t,s_recovered_2);
legend('recovered rect');
title('recovered rect using wiener filter');
```

Comment: Removing the noise and computing the simple inverse filter reveals the original rect (provided I do 's_recovered_1 = real(ifft(S_temp));' which I have changed the above code to reflect).  I expect the output of the simple inverse filter to give large values since I am mostly dividing by small values.  This more or less matches the output I actually get.  I think my main problem now is in computing the Wiener filter.  I have updated my code to reflect what I think it is now, but I am very unsure of this and it still doesn't produce anything like the original rect at all.

Comment: I have also tried computing the wiener filter by directly computing what I think are the two sided power spectral densities of I and R.  I have updated the code above to reflect this.  I get something like a sinc now.  So this may be better but it still not close.

Comment: and I have tried also taking the ifft twice with regards to the wiener filtering, which is stupid I know, but it gives a rect of the right amplitude (since the first ifft is a sinc), but the width is wrong...
I have updated my code above to show the line for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that I was dividing by the wrong denominator when calculating the Wiener Filter.  I also now calculate the |...|^2 (power spectral density) of each term in the Wiener Filter using the straightforward abs(...)^2 way.  The code above reflects these changes.
Hope this is helpful to any noobs like myself :)

Comment: im trying to do the same but your code divides by zero now resulting in all NaN`s for the wiener deconvolution.

Comment: Yes, you have to check for NaN values.

Comment: Hi, I tried running your code but it says I and R are not defined. What are the values of I and R?

Comment: @MoneyBall It's been a while since I last looked at this, but I believe *I = FxS* where *F = fft(f)* and *S = fft(s)* (f is the original signal and s is a rect)